# Designing microservice architecture for Object Storage

Tags: architecture, microservices

I am trying to design a microservice architecture for object storage. I read many resources about microservices. But I still have some questions. I have some ideas in my mind which I will explain but please point me to right direction if my designs have flaws. So lets start with my ideas and questions. By the way we can use amazon s3 for an example. Just like amazon s3 my users will create/update/delete buckets, store objects inside those buckets and will do other object operations like updating, deleting, versioning etc. Also users can create api keys and secrets to authenticate their requests.

Since this is my first rodeo with microservices I want to keep things simple. For now I have 3 services in my mind which are "Auth Service", "Bucket Service" and "Object Service". I have actually 2 design ideas base on how my services communicate. First one is communicating with rest.

[image: Basic Rest]

This is a very basic version of my design.

Using a single database is not recommended according to the resources I read. I am willing to use different database for every service. Lets say user sent a request to get an object. With a monolithic app its very easy to do.

- User sends a request.
- Server authenticates the request by doing necessary things with api key.
- Server checks the bucket of requested object if its exist.
- Finally checks the objects and returns the object data if its exist.

What about when I have those 3 different services ?  When user request, gateway will redirect the request to Object Service. Object Service will ask Auth Service to authenticate the request. If everything is ok Object Service will ask Bucket Service if the bucket is exist. If bucket is exist Object service will check the object and will return the result if object is also exist. (Please share your ideas if you have a better flow in your mind) Also its very easy when I have a single database. Normally object table has Foreign Key to bucket service. But when I divide those into 2 separated database I will still keep the bucket_id column in object table. When I need info about a bucket I will go to Bucket Service with the id.
It this the right approach ?

One reason to have microservices is scalability. So what happens when I multiple instances of the services.

[image: Multi Rest]

Should I have a database for every service instance in group or single database for the all identical services ?

I may put gateways in front of every group so I won't have to deal with lots of ip addresses and load balancing. Also the same gateway or another one can be used to communication between services. But obviously these approach becomes problematic as the number of service types increase. So as the resources I have read suggested I may use message broker like RabbitMQ.

[image: Message Multi]

Users send an sync request. But as soon as I use the message broker it becomes async. I don't want to return 202 accepted and check for the result with another request. Its simple if user wants to do something with bucket or object user should get the response right away. So how can I implement the same example we discussed above.

For example, when user sends request to get object info, gateway will redirect this request to object service. Object service will send a message like "authorize-request". Auth Service will pick the message and will do the necessary things then will send message like "request-authorized". Then something close to this will happen between Object Service and Bucket Service to get bucket info or to check if its exist. So basically Object service will send and receive messages. And it needs to hold user request till it can respond to it right ? What is the right way to do this ?

Another problem is when I have multiple Object Service instance, user request will be processed by only one of them but if all of them listening for the messages from other services how I will send the message to the right one ? Should I route messages to specific services ? Or should I send this message to all services but these services may check with given id if the message related to the service instance ?

Probably I will need another service to handle streams. For example when user wants to upload or download a file. I am planning to use a distributed file storage solution like ceph. So how my system should handle the the requests which requires data stream. Would be really good if anyone can explain step by step.

These are just my ideas and questions based on my readings. I would like to hear yours even if its opposite of mine. How you would design such system ? How would you split into services ? Which communication type you would chose to communicate services ?

If the examples and the information I gave are not enough feel free to ask anything in comments.
I am very excited to hear from you guys. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't bother putting another service abstraction in front of the bucket service.  It's already a service, you are just borrowing complexity with no advantage.

Now, for the sake of argument, let's pretend you should have a bucket service (don't), then the way to abstract it is to have your bucket have an identity that is opaque to those that are using it.  It might be "bucket_id", but you could abstract this a bit and make it a URI so that you can dump the bucket concept in the future if you decide to do things like store it on a file system, or a database.  Regardless, that identifier is opaque to the object service.

If you want to buy the complexity that is async (not saying you should or shouldn't), you are pushing the merging of the "experience" to some layer that will have to deal with it the request/response synchronization.  That could be to the calling service (object service), it could be to the calling API (giving them a location to call-back to to retrieve the data), or it could go all the way to the end-user (we as human beings synchronize asynchronous experiences all the time).  It just depends on where you push the complexity of waiting for the asynchronous experience to complete.  In the example you gave (auth), you have pushed the asynchronous -> synchronous conversion into your calling services.

For responding to an async request, you can either address it the response so that it gets routed to the right requestor (think a topic queue with request-ids), or you can return a URI synchronously that the client can poll for the response.

For streams, just return a URI that the client can open to retrieve the stream.  Uploading is trickier as the client will likely not have a URI that can be provided, so it probably won't work.  HTTP is inherently a stream though, so I don't know what the value-prop there is.  Try taking a strong look at S3 and how they handle this, there are a lot of patterns for solving the issues you are trying to solve.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you say object service and bucket service can be merged into one right ? It seems reasonable to me. Another thing is I was not sure about holding the request while waiting messages from message queue. So it is totally valid thing to do ?

Comment: Think of S3 like you would a database, put it in the same kind of layer (not tier) as any other database access.  There are scenarios where you would encapsulate a database in its own service that had no business logic, but those scenarios are few and only for very specific situations (like you have multiple databases you need to support simultaneously and transparently).  And yes, the async->sync resolution has to happen somewhere, either it's being pushed up to a higher layer, or it's staying in the object service.  Wherever it is pushed to will have more complexity, and poor scaling.